# JAVA - Lucene search query - hyphens with wildcards

Tags: search, lucene, wildcard

I've got a huge problem with Lucene (v3.5) search query. I'm trying to retrieve strings with hyphens using query containing hyphens and a wildcard sign(s), example:
names in db: 
A4RER-88-22331
A4RER-22-32555
B3B8B-22-32555

query: A4RER-*

I've used WhitespaceAnalyzer (earlier StandardAnalyzer) but... the query is working for "A4RER*" but not "A4RER-*" :(
I've googled a lot already, but still can't find a solution for this. Is there a simple way to force it to work?

thanks for any hint/help/snippet/anything

Comment: You need to use a tokenizer that does not break on -. WhitespaceAnalyzer probably breaks on - by default.

Comment: is the - acting as a NOT here ??? can you try escape and check ?

Comment: @bmargulies I'm not really familiar with writing a Tokenizer, yet. Thanks for this hint. I'll start 'googling' how to write a custom tokenizer right now. Thank you.

Comment: @Jayendra Nope... this doesn't work :( still no results from sych query with escaped hyphens.

Comment: @bmargulies hmm. Just found this: http://karticles.com/nosql/lucene_custom_tokenizer.html it clearly shows WhitespaceTokenizer does not stop at "-". Now I'm confused. I'll try to write own tokenizer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When using a WildcardQuery, replace hyphens with question marks. The question mark represents a single character.

Change this: "query: A4RER-*"

To this: "query: A4RER?*"